# How to solve "Connection failed" in Google+ login in android?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

Recently, I did a code on Google+ login. I need to allow Google+ login to a user from a page and pass the control to the next page using Intent.
Heres what I did

`if (view == imageViewgoogleplus) {
        str_button_clicked = "googleplus";
        dogoogleLogin();
    } 


private void dogoogleLogin() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    signInWithGplus();

}

private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {

        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;

            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int value) {

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionresult) {

    System.out.println("Connection failed");
    if (!connectionresult.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                connectionresult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        mConnectionResult = connectionresult;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    getProfileInformation();
}

private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`

When I run the code, it should get the credentials from the user's mobile and then it should do the login. I am continuously getting Connection failed from Google. I have setup the SHA1 properly and I have also provided proper permissions in manifest file. Still I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help.

Comment: Clearing the cache and data for Google Play Services worked for me.

Comment: The problem still persists & it is showing "Connection Failed". Help pls!

Comment: I am also receiving this error. It is error code 17. According to the docs, "there is no resolution for this sign-in failure". I have tried clearing cache/data, uninstall and reinstall app and still no fix. Have you figured anything out?

Comment: I fixed it when i put the correct google-services.json, with the correct SHA1.

Comment: There is callback by the name onConnectionFailed in that log this way Log.d("AP_NAME"," connection failed "+ result.getErrorCode()+" and "+result.toString()); and then you have the error and then google it. Hope it helps

Comment: you've to share more info about your connection failed.Check onconnectionFailure function and print more info about result.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder i got same error of error code 17 did you get solution?